# Box2D joints stretching out of place - allowing objects to pass through. How can I make them more "tight"

Tags: python, box2d, game-physics

I'm trying to make a rope bridge style element in box2d (actually pybox2d)

The shapes are connected with revolute joints, and all appears fine at first. But when too much pressure (or weight) is put on the "bridge" the revolute joints flex to a point where the object passes through.

I've tried adding distance joints & rope joints along side the revolute joints to try and hold it together but nothing seems to work.

(also tried the joint damping ratio and frequency)

Is there a easy trick for the bridge to catch the object without it falling through?

[image]

longer and wider blocks also don't seem to make a difference

[image]

EDIT:

I've made the blocks longer for a second time, increased the overlap and
its at least "holding" smaller objects. But they can still pass through with enough pressue.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the simulation parameters (e.g. more substeps or similar)?

Comment: yes :( i've got 60hz step with position and velocity iterations a 7.  Pixels per m is 45.

Comment: How about longer segments like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZT4VP29_OqE (which is Box2d but otherwise unrelated)?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't make a difference, see my update.

Comment: With your last edit, how about just limiting the force the user can exert on the object (maybe especially if it's in contact with something)?

Comment: Have you also tried enabling bullet mode on the objects that you want the bridge to hold? Does that help any? Fundamentally speaking, I suspect that joint processing will also need to be added to the time-of-impact phase processing to make your joints much tighter but I don't believe Box2D has that capability. Enabling bullet mode on the bodies involved and using the other suggestions mentioned so far are probably your best options for mitigating the problem for now.